# Angular 4 instance variable is undefined inside a method

Tags: angular, variables, typescript, instance

I have this code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'unb-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.html'
})
 export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit  {

@Input() brand: string;

controlador:boolean=false;
overlay:string="";

@Input() menus:any = [{
  name: 'Início',
  icon: 'home',
  router: 'home',
  path:'home'
}];

private html: string ='';


constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private navbarService: NavbarService){

}

ngOnInit() {
    //this.carregarMenuDinamico();
}


carregarMenuDinamico(){
    this.authenticationService.getUrlFromBarramento()
        .subscribe(res=> {
                this.navbarService.createTemplate (AuthenticationService.base_url)
                    .subscribe (res => {
                        this.html = res;
                    });
            },
            error => {
                this.authenticationService.getUrlFromConfig()
                    .subscribe(response =>{
                        this.navbarService.createTemplate (AuthenticationService.base_url)
                            .subscribe (res => { 
                                this.html = res;
                            });
                    });
            });
}

carregarBars(){
  if(this.controlador){
    this.controlador =false;
    this.overlay = "none";
  }else{
    this.controlador =true;
    this.overlay = "block";
  }

}

}
```

When this line is execute this.html = res; the this.html is undefined always, and I don't know why.

The code compile correctly with webpack and this method run without erros but never atribute any value to this.html is ever undefined.

I try to put a console.log but this happen:

this thing apears in debug in chrome

[debug in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPC7Q.jpg)

But this thing appen when coneols.log this variables

[use console.log in res and this.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0t43.jpg)

But nothing change in . And i don't know why.

Comment: If it's undefined, it means that res is also undefined, which means that navbarService.createTemplate() returns an Observable emitting undefined. You should use switchMap() instead of subscribing inside a subscribe callback. I also have a hard time understanding the point of calling this.authenticationService.getUrlFromXxx, since you don't doanything with the event it emits.

Comment: when is it showing undefined ?where are you trying to use this.html ?

Comment: The return of variable res  "<li class="active"> <a ng-reflect-router-link="/categoriaperguntalist" href="#/categoriaperguntalist"><i class="material-icons">chrome_reader_mode</i></li>" but is never atached to this.html, because it's always undefined. I think it's a bug in Angular 4.

Comment: And this  this.authenticationService.getUrlFromXxx, because i need to authenticate url from user it's part of a code for implement oauth2 in client, but it's work correct. Only this line doesn't work this.html = res;

Comment: So, you print res before calling `this.html = res;`, and it displays something, and if you add `console.log(this.html)`right after that line of code, it prints undefined? I find it hard to believe. Please do that, and tell what is printed. I.e. replace `this.html = res;`by `console.log('res = ' + res); this.html = res; console.log('html = ' + this.html);`.

Comment: Vikhyath Maiya I try to use this.html in navbar.html in this line: <div [innerHtml]="html"></div> because in this line i insert html dinamically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670366/debugging-angular-app)

Comment: As stated in the duplicate this is a closure issue. If you do something like `var a = this.html`, you can see value in `a` when debugging. Also check the link provided in the comments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: ...and as a sidenote, always provide all information in question. Nowhere in your question are you mentioning that this is about debugging, we just found out that about the additional info you provided in an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.authenticationService.getUrlFromBarramento()
        .subscribe(res=> {
                this.navbarService.createTemplate (AuthenticationService.base_url)
                    .subscribe (res => {
                        this.html = res;
                    });
            },
```

This might be trivial, but I think you need to use two different variables for the callback when you are chaining up two observables like res1 when you are subscribing for getUrlFromBarramento() and res2 or something else for createTemplate.

Comment: I changed name of variable but stil don't work correct.